# In Visual Studio 2022 (with Resharper), what setting controls the color of the "inline" error hints?

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2022

I'm running Visual Studio 2022 with Resharper in the Dark theme.  I see the following inline UI element for build errors, which is very hard to read with the black text on a very dark background.  I'm unsure if this is being displayed by Resharper, or by Visual Studio directly, but I'd like to change the colors to make this more readable.  What color setting controls the font color of this element?
[image]

I've found several "Inline X" color settings in the options dialog, but none seem to affect this UI element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by "Inline Diagnostics - Error" (in the case of errors like your screenshot shows) in Tools → Options → Environment → Font and Colors.  I do find it a bit weird that it's black text in dark theme for you.  I don't use this diagnostic feature, but when I turned it on to find this answer out, it defaulted to white for me.

Here you can see I changed the foreground to lime and the background to cyan and you can see the UI element updated accordingly.

[image: Inline Diagnostics - Error option in fonts and colors]

Comment: Very odd. That setting was also set to White when I checked it, and there was no immediate effect when I tried changing it.  However, after changing the setting, restarting Visual Studio, changing it back to white, and restarting again, it started displaying correctly.  I guess it was just another incident where Visual Studio got confused.  Thank you for pointing me to the correct setting!